# Prove there exists $\mathbf \xi$ such that $||\nabla F(\mathbf \xi)||\leq2$.

Tags: analysis

> Suppose $B\subseteq\mathbb R^d,\;\Omega=\{\mathbf x\,\big|\,||\mathbf x||\leq1\}$, $\Omega\subseteq B$ and $|F(\mathbf x)|\leq1$. Prove there exists $\mathbf \xi$ such that $||\nabla F(\mathbf \xi)||\leq2$.

Suppse $\mathbf x,\,\mathbf y\in \Omega$, then by mean value theorem, we have 
$$
F(\mathbf x)-F(\mathbf y)=F_1'(\mathbf\xi)(x_1-y_1)+\cdots+F_d'(\mathbf\xi)(x_d-y_d).
$$

I have though about Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I get an inequality of converse direction. So I need some help.

Comment: $F$ maps from where to where? Note that the mean value thm can only be applied to functions defined on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: $F$ is a real-valued function defined on $B$ of course.

Comment: Not "of course"! It could have been defined on $B$ or could have mapped to $\mathbb R^m$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $||\nabla F(\xi)|| > 2$ for all $\xi \in \Omega$, and define the function $g : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ given by 
$$g(\xi) = F(\xi) - 2||\xi||.$$ 
Now, since $F$ is continuous on $\Omega$, $g$ is also continuous on $\Omega$, and thus by compactness of $\Omega$, $g$ attains its maximum at some $\xi \in \Omega$. Suppose $||\xi|| < 1$. Note that near $\xi$ we have 
$$F(\xi') = F(\xi) + \nabla F(\xi) \cdot (\xi' - \xi) + o(||\xi' - \xi||).$$
By assumption, $||\nabla F(\xi)|| = 2 + \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$, so letting $v$ be the unit vector in the direction of $\nabla F(\xi)$, this gives $F(\xi + xv) = F(\xi) + (2 + \varepsilon)x + o(|x|)$, hence for sufficiently small $x > 0$, $F(\xi + xv) > F(\xi) + 2x$. But since $||\xi|| < 1$, for sufficiently small $x$ we have $||\xi + xv|| < 1$, so there is some $x$ satisfying both of these conditions, which satisfies 
\begin{align*}
g(\xi + xv) 
&= F(\xi + xv) - 2||\xi + xv|| \\
&> (F(\xi) + 2x) - 2(||\xi|| + x) \\
&= g(\xi)
\end{align*}
contradicting maximality of $\xi$. Thus any maximizer $\xi$ has $||\xi|| = 1$. Since $g(0) = F(0)$, and $0$ is not a maximizer, this means that any maximizer $\xi$ has $g(\xi) = F(\xi) - 2||\xi|| = F(\xi) - 2 > F(0)$, hence $F(\xi) - F(0) > 2$. But since $|F| \leq 1$, we must have $|F(\xi) - F(0)| \leq 2$, a contradiction.

**Update:**

It's been bugging me that the bound is $2$ and not $1$, which is the bound you get from the MVT in the one-dimensional case. Here's a way to modify the proof to show that there must be some $\xi \in \Omega$ with $||\nabla F(\xi)|| \leq 1$.

Similar to before, suppose $||\nabla F|| > 1$ on $\Omega$. Repeat the analysis above to maximize the function $g_+(\xi) = F(\xi) - ||\xi||$. At the end you find some $\xi_+$ with $||\xi_+|| = 1$ and $F(\xi_+) - 1 > F(0)$. Repeating this last part with $-F$ instead of $F$ (maximizing $g_-(\xi) = -F(\xi) - ||\xi||$) gives some $\xi_-$ with $||\xi_-|| = 1$ and $-F(\xi_-) - 1 > -F(0)$. Adding the two inequalities we've found gives $F(\xi_+) - F(\xi_-) - 2 > 0$, which is again impossible since we must have $|F(\xi_+) - F(\xi_-)| \leq 2$. It follows that $||\nabla F(\xi)|| \leq 1$ somewhere (and this is the best possible).

Comment: Wow! Congrats! Really nice answer!

Comment: corrected, thanks